# Usage of sun.misc.SharedSecrets

Tags: java

I found this little gem in our codebase at work recently. I have to confess that I have absolutely no idea why this enum was written in this way (names changed to protect the innocent):

```
package foo.bar;

import sun.misc.SharedSecrets;
import foo.baz.HasAGetValuesMethod;

public enum MysteryEnum implements HasAGetValuesMethod {

   THINGY, BOB;

   @Override
   public MysteryEnum[] getValues() {
      return SharedSecrets.getJavaLangAccess().getEnumConstantsShared(MysteryEnum .class);
   }
}
```

In the getValues() method instead of simply calling `MysteryEnum.values()` it's using something called `sun.misc.SharedSecret` to get a handle to something called `sun.misc.JavaLangAccess`, then using *that* to get an array of all the enum values. The Javadoc on that class tells you what the method does, but I can't find much on *why* you would want to call it.

The developer that wrote this is no longer around, so I can't ask him. I'm going to ask my team anyway, but I have a feeling that the answer will be: "Don't know why it does that, but better not change it". For the moment, I'm assuming that this is either an odd case of someone not knowing that the `values()` method exists, or that my ignorance of the sun.misc libraries is causing me to miss something obvious to others. Any idea's why this code was written this way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The method returns the same array without reflection or copying/cloning the underlying array.  This improves performance, but is not a good idea to exposes a mutable array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    System.out.println(SharedSecrets.getJavaLangAccess().getEnumConstantsShared(AccessMode.class));
AccessMode[] ams = SharedSecrets.getJavaLangAccess().getEnumConstantsShared(AccessMode.class);
ams[1] = ams[2]; // don't do this !!
System.out.println(EnumSet.allOf(AccessMode.class));
```

prints

```
[Ljava.nio.file.AccessMode;@330cdec1
[Ljava.nio.file.AccessMode;@330cdec1
[Ljava.nio.file.AccessMode;@330cdec1
[READ, EXECUTE, EXECUTE]
```

Instead of using this method, what I do is use my own cached copy

```
// cannot be modified.
private static final AccessMode[] ACCESS_MODES = AccessMode.values();
```

Comment: I see. So it's a performance hack. By the looks of it, quite a brittle one.

Comment: Its obscure enough, under `sun.*`, that you should know to avoid it or handle with great care.  Similar to `sun.misc.Unsafe` ;)

Comment: After having a hunt about - it looks like the values() method is actually added by the compiler (it isn't on the Javadoc for Enum). If that is the case, then how can we be sure that the above is even optimised in any way? Perhaps the compiler is optimized to return a handle to the same array wherever values is called? Is there any way of checking this?

Comment: Do you mean like the checks I did? ;)

Comment: No, I'm talking about how smart the compiler is in regards to calls to values(). Is it smart enough to detect that the array is not being modified in the calling code, and so return a handle to the same array reference, or is it guaranteed to return a new array every time... or what? And is this documented anywhere?

Comment: The generated method returns a new array at each call. The Sun engineers tested what the most efficient solution was, without compromising encapsulation by returning a cached array, and they decided that returning a new array was the best solution. The cost is ridiculous. This hack is a bad hack: it compromises correctness for speed, doesn't probably gain anything significant, and could have been implemented without using non-standard API.

Comment: Even if you felt there was a performance advantage, there is a simple workaround which is not as ugly.

Comment: @PeterLawrey actually, ACCESS_MODES can be modified..  final only affects the reference,  you can still do ACCESS_MODES[2] = {some_access_mode_value} ...

Answer (score 4):

Basically [`SharedSecret`](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/SharedSecrets.html):

> A repository of "shared secrets", which are a mechanism for
>       calling implementation-private methods in another package without
>       using reflection.

The code returns the enum constants by reading the class and returning the constants back (without needing to do reflection calls). This is dynamic in a way that if a new enum constant is added to the enum, the `getValues()` method will return the added enums (no need to change code all over the show).

Comment: I don't get it. If you add further enum values, then call values() you also get the added enums along with the original ones. What does getValues(), as implemented, give you above that?

Comment: It just return the exact, original values back (without the need of cloning or caching it). Basically, it's a way of bypassing JVM stack and getting the direct value out.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/JavaLangAccess.html#getEnumConstantsShared%28Class%29) says:

> Returns the elements of an enum class or null if the Class object does
>   not represent an enum type; the result is uncloned, cached, and shared
>   by all callers.

So, unless the point was to provide a shared array, so that anyone could break everything by setting one of its elements to null, or sorting it, or whatever (which could have been done by caching the result of the `values()` method), my guess is also that this line is there due to the incompetence of the previous developer.

I would write a unit test, then replace it with a call to `values()` and check that the unit test still passes.

Answer (score 1):

Just for information:
I was looking into the implementation of EnumMap and found the same code snippet where all enum values are fetched from the class name.

```
/**
 * Returns all of the values comprising K.
 * The result is uncloned, cached, and shared by all callers.
 */
private static <K extends Enum<K>> K[] getKeyUniverse(Class<K> keyType) {
    return SharedSecrets.getJavaLangAccess()
                                    .getEnumConstantsShared(keyType);
}
```